# Read a parent and child node from xml

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get 2 values out of an XML.

Currently, when I run the code below, I get just the information in "OutTime". I know why this is happening, but I am unsure how to change it to get the information I would like.

What I would like displayed is: All names under the 'People' and the 'OutTime'.

*Example:*

**OutPut:**
S7-JEHILL 20:47

**XML Sheet**

```
<Times>
  <People>
    <S7-JEHILL>
      <OutTime>20:47</OutTime>
    </S7-JEHILL>
  </People>
</Times>
```

**Current Code**

```
 Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\TimeStamps.xml")
        Dim child As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Times/People")
        If Not (child Is Nothing) Then
            Dim nr As New XmlNodeReader(child)
            While nr.Read()
                NameList.Items.Add(nr.Value)
            End While
        End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `System.XML` to your Reference. This is just another approach for XML file nodes manipulation.

```
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument 'For loading xml file to read
    Dim ArticleNodeList As XmlNodeList 'For getting the list of main/parent nodes

    xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\TimeStamps.xml") 'loading the xml file, insert your file here
    ArticleNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("People") 'Setting all <People> node to list
    For Each articlenode As XmlNode In ArticleNodeList 'Looping through <People> node
        For Each basenode As XmlNode In articlenode 'Looping all <People> childnodes
            Dim result As String = ""
            result = basenode.Name 'use .name to get the xml node name
            For Each Node As XmlNode In basenode 'Looping all childnodes of basenode
                result = result & " " & Node.InnerText 'use .Innertext to get the xml node value
            Next
            NameList.Items.Add(result) 'Adding Value to your variable
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

First use an XPath query to get all nodes under the  tag. Then use the `ChildNodes` collections to get the relevant information of a)  the tag name and b) the OutTime value:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Xml As String = "<Times><People><S7-JEHILL><OutTime>20:47</OutTime></S7-JEHILL></People></Times>"
    Dim Doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim Xpath As String = "/Times/People"
    Dim ElementList As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(xpath)
    Dim PersonName, OutTime As String

    'load xml to document
    Doc.LoadXml(Xml)

    'iterate elements in <People>
    For Each Element As Xml.XmlElement In ElementList
        'gets the S7-JEHILL value from the tag name
        PersonName = Element.ChildNodes(0).Name
        'gets the 20:47 from the tag value i.e. inner XML
        OutTime = Element.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).InnerXml
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", PersonName, OutTime))
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```